# Printing to an Epson PictureMate from Java

Tags: java, printing

I'm to use the Java printing API to print a JPG to an Epson PictureMate photo printer. I want the print to take up the entire page. The image prints but it has an eighth of an inch of unprinted space on right edge. Here's the code I'm using:

```java
public void printImage(File image) throws Exception {
  PrintRequestAttributeSet aset = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
  aset.add(OrientationRequested.REVERSE_LANDSCAPE);
  aset.add(MediaSizeName.JAPANESE_POSTCARD);
  DocPrintJob printerJob = printService.createPrintJob();       
  FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(image);
  Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(fis, DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.JPEG, null);
  printerJob.print(doc, aset);
  fis.close();
}
```

I thought the the `JAPANESE_POSTCARD` size was correct but it seems to small for 4"x6" prints. I also tried setting `MediaPrintableArea` to 4"x6" but that didn't work either. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I know there is some (potential) internal wrangling of the Paper that goes on after you pass it to the `PrintJob`, basically it's trying to valid that the paper size and margins can work with the specified printer (from experience).

However, you might to take a read of http://www.jpedal.org/PDFblog/2009/06/java-printing-page-size-problem/ as it might have some ideas on how to over come some of them.

As to how to them apply that back to the `PrintService`s API is another question ;)